# Keep copy/clone of an array which needs to be modified several times

Tags: php, arrays

I have an original array which is getting modified like e.g.

```
private function test()
{
    $myArray = array(1,2,3);
    $array = $this->modifyArray($myArray, 1);
}

private function modifyArray($paramArray, $someValue)
{

    foreach ($paramArray as &$item) {
        $item += $someValue;
    }

    return $paramArray;

}
```

To my understanding **$myArray** and **$array** will be [2,3,4] at the end of function 'test'.

But what is the correct approach if I want to re-do this and call modifyArray again like:

```
private function test()
{
    $myArray = array(1,2,3);
    $array = $this->modifyArray($myArray, 1);
    // new call
    $anotherArray = $this->modifyArray($myArray, 2);
}
```

To my understanding **$myArray**, **$array** and **$anotherArray** will now be [4,5,6] and not $array = [2,3,4] and $anotherArray = [3,4,5] which is my intention.

Or am I totally misguided here?

Comment: `$myArray` is never changed in your examples. `$array` is returned from the function as a modified copy.

Comment: probably you want `private function modifyArray(&$paramArray, $someValue)` - note & before paramArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **are** misguided here. The variable `$paramArray` inside `modifyArray` exists only inside `modifyArray` and is not modified. It only returns the changed array back. This means:

```
$myArray = array(1,2,3); // will still be [1,2,3]
$array = $this->modifyArray($myArray, 1); // $array will be [2,3,4], because [1,2,3] is passed
// new call
$anotherArray = $this->modifyArray($myArray, 2); // $anotherArray will be [3,4,5] because [1,2,3] is passed
```

If you want another behavior, you should link `$paramArray` to the passed array with `&`:

```
private function modifyArray(&$paramArray, $someValue)
```

Now the result would be:

```
$myArray = array(1,2,3); // will still be [1,2,3]
$array = $this->modifyArray($myArray, 1); // $array will be [2,3,4], because [1,2,3] is passed and $myArray is now [2,3,4]
// new call
$anotherArray = $this->modifyArray($myArray, 2); // $anotherArray will be [4,5,6] because [2,3,4] is passed and $myArray is now [4,5,6]
```

Comment: Thanks - and to the comments as well - this is clarifying a lot for me.